# Creating custom components for all html tags in React

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a question to experienced guys, that have made shareable components with React. Is it reasonable to create custom react components per each existing html tag? I mean for example if I can use an html `div`, is there some benefit of creating my own custom `<Div>` let's say, that would get some specific parameters as props (stylings etc.)

Comment: Almost anything that you could think of adding to the custom component, you can do it without making it as a React component as well. I don't see creating custom components solving any purpose

Comment: Like everything else, it depends on what you're trying to do... if you just want to add style, use css, that's literally what its made for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it wouldn't have to much sense for `div` because it is just a general container. But for typography tags like `h1, h2...` and links this can be a great idea. If the design is consistent this can help you to make your code cleaner. But of course, everything depends on the project.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. And what about creating a component  `<Element>` and pass a tag name as a prop so I would basically be/cover all the html elements?

Comment: `<Element>` component to decide which component should be rendered? Like `<Element tag='h1'>` instead of just using `<H1>`? For me it seems like unnecessary complexity so I wouldn't do that.

Comment: Yes, exactly as you described.

Comment: I'd just use separate components like `<H1>, <H2>...`

Answer (score 2):

Probably late to the party, but I'm currently designing a system like you described. I think a higher order component would be the way to pull this off. This is the beginning of the system I've implemented

```
function style (attr) {
  const background = {
    primary: 'blue',
    ...
  }

  const color = {...}

  const size = {
    padding: {...},
    ...
  }

  return {
    background: background[attr.background] || undefined,
    color: color[attr.color] || undefined,
    size: {
      padding: size.padding[attr.size] || undefined,
      borderRadius: size.borderRadius[attr.size] || undefined
    }
  }

}

export const Tag = tag => React.memo(props => {
  const Tag = tag
  const theme = style(props)
  return (
    <Tag
      className={classNames(
        tag,
        props.className,
        theme.background !== undefined ? `bg-${theme.background}`: '',
        theme.color !== undefined ? `text-${theme.color}`: '',
        theme.size.padding !== undefined ? `pad-${theme.size.padding}`: '',
        theme.size.borderRadius !== undefined ? `br-${theme.size.borderRadius}`: ''
      )}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Tag>
  )
})

export const Section = Tag('section');
Section.displayName = "Section";
export const Article = Tag('article');
Article.displayName = "Article";
export const Header = Tag('header');
Header.displayName = "Header";
export const Footer = Tag('footer');
Footer.displayName = "Footer";
export const Span = Tag('span');
Span.displayName = "Span";
export const Strong = Tag('strong');
Strong.displayName = "Strong";
export const Div = Tag('div');
Div.displayName = "Div";
export const Em = Tag('em');
Em.displayName = "Em";
export const Ul = Tag('ul');
Ul.displayName = "Ul";
export const Li = Tag('li');
Li.displayName = "Li";
export const H1 = Tag('h1');
H1.displayName = "H1";
export const H2 = Tag('h2');
H2.displayName = "H2";
export const H3 = Tag('h3');
H3.displayName = "H3";
export const H4 = Tag('h4');
H4.displayName = "H4";
export const H5 = Tag('h5');
H5.displayName = "H5";
export const H6 = Tag('h6');
H6.displayName = "H6";
export const P = Tag('p');
P.displayName = "P";
```